# changing win 7 registry with c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

it should be this simple.  this code looks good.  it doesnt crash.  so why doesnt it do what it says to do?  I cant change anything in the registry like this but all google searches say this is how it should be.  any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\",true);
        myKey.SetValue("AutoAdminLogon", "1");   

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be dealing with Win7's "shadow registry" issue wherein some registry changes are not made to the "actual" registry, but a "shadow" copy that protects the original in the event of malevolent access. Registry changes are redirected to a user-specific region of the registry, but are rendered to appear as though they are in HKLM (as in your example).

Registry virtualization was introduced in Vista, I believe, but is at least a good candidate to explain your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx
Failing this, you may be making changes against the Wow64 node of the registry. Check for your changes under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon and see if your changes are being made there instead. On 64-bit versions of Windows, 32 bit code runs under the WOW subsystem, and registry calls from such apps are routed to the Wow6432 node in the registry - all unbeknownst to the calling 32-bit app.

Comment: The key point is that the program runs elevated (as administrator), then the registry key change will work as expected (no registry virtualization occurs under elevation). It is mentioned in the article you linked.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that, however,  the following line of code works in a powershell script

Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -name AutoAdminLogon -value 0

Comment: Because I believe the Powershell script necessarily runs under elevation.

Comment: ok, so i closed visual studio, right clicked and ran as administrator and it did not change the registry.  i even try running the executable as admin and still the changes dont take place.

Comment: I also cannot find  HKEY_USERS\< User SID >_Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\Contoso.  

thats where the linked article says to find the actual changed keys, but contoso does not exist.  but it shouldnt as the article also states that this registry virtualization does not exist on future versions of windows (after vista) nor does it exist on 64-bit Processes.

Right now I am working on this at my home pc, but at work I have all the priviliges needed to change registry keys, my user id is as good as administrator.  im not sure if this helps anyone

Comment: Here's a different notion - are you running 32-bit code on a 64-bit box, perchance?

Comment: hate to ask this, how can i find out?

Comment: No problem asking. We're all here to help each other! I modified my answer to include the place to look in the registry if you're really making changes to the 32-bit WOW portion of the registry. See if that helps.

Comment: wow, ok, this makes a lot of sense, a tutorial i did online had me create a key in the root of software, when i searched for it i found it in wow6432n.  and that is exactly where the changes are taking place in my c# code.  so, how do I run this under elevation as lex said earlier.  after trying to run as admin and the changes not happening im out of ideas

Comment: There are two different things going here. Privilege elevation is entirely different from whether your app is 32-bit or 64-bit. The location you *want* to change is native to the 64-bit registry on a 64-bit system, and a 64-bit OS always routes calls to such a location from 32-bit apps to the Wow6432 node as noted. You'll need to rewrite your app as a 64-bit executable to talk to the "native" part of the registry the way you're wanting.

Comment: Clarfication: I said "rewrite" your app - you should be able to recompile it as a 64-bit app and solve the problem.

Comment: No, but the *application you build* may be either 32- or 64-bits. Visual Studio 2010, while a 32-bit application, can *create* 64-bit applications. Look at the targets in the Configuration Manager, and you'll probably see your current target as x86. That's 32-bit. Change (or add) a configuration for AnyCPU or x64, and set that as your target, and recompile your app.

Comment: yea, see i went to the configuration manager, i figured i was in the right spot, just didnt know what to do

Comment: My pleasure! Glad my answer/responses were helpful!

Comment: yup, that worked.  wow, this has really been a pain in my side for a bit.  i resorted to having my application simply run powershell,  this is awesome, thanks a bunch